# Propositional logic in other domains

Tags: propositional-calculus

The transfer of propositional logic to other domains has been investigated ([as mentioned here for example](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46265/is-propositional-logic-present-in-all-languages/46267?fbclid=IwAR1f3H84lR_jOsCpsdVHs-sizZRM87HPWHpzFNXmWC2kF8qn7ZjQdXq27IY#46267)). By domain here I mean an area that has some regularities and is reflected, for example, in the theory of multiple intelligences. I see that logic was first investigated in relation to language, but later the possibility of displaying individual concepts was added, for example in the form of Euler diagrams. These two-dimensional graphic objects are no longer related to language, they follow their own laws (maybe?). And here it already looks like, according to the theory of multiple intelligences, we are entering the visual-spatial domain. Could we go further? Model the concepts of propositional logic in some computer-generated 3D objects, or explain this kind of logic on the laws of nature (ecology) or music?

If a language where it can identify logical conjunctions and propositional logic describes these domains, it should probably work. But I'm rather asking about some specific studies that would illustrate propositional logic in these domains. Or one can rather assume that these domains operate according to other logics (for example, fuzzy logic) and the language was just an artificial imprecise description of these domains, so propositional logic cannot be sought here.

Comment: Quite confused... Propositional logic **is** a (very very simplified) model of natural language. What does it mean to extend it "to other domains"?

Comment: Usually, with "domain" in logic we mean *domain of discourse*: this is part of the interpretation of the logical system: the logical system (e.g. propositional logic) is "topic neutral", meaning that it consider the laws governing the logical connectives (like logical conjunctions): rthe basic assumption of prop logic is that these laws do not change wrt to the topic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Extending it to other domains may mean then to display this model in 3D objects? What do Euler diagrams have to do with prepositional logic, if this logic is a mode of natural language?

Comment: Euler diagram is a way to interpret formulas, like truth table.

Comment: It seems that you are thinking to propositional logic wrt Euler diagram as a "science" applied to a certain "natural facts" like e.g. botanic that describe flowers. It is not so: we do not use propositional logic to "describe" Euler diagrams.